C# Process.Start() "access is denied" error when redirecting standard output
I am trying to create and start a process from my .Net application using the following code:
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "powershell.exe",
    Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File {ps1FilePath}",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};
using (Process process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
{   
    process.Start();
   // Some code...
}

process.Start() is failing, throwing an "Access id denied" exception only when I set RedirectStandardOutput = true. If I remove that from my startInfo, the process starts and completes just fine. I tried to debug and found that the issue is related with pipe creation for the output redirection, but I couldn't debug more because this is Windows code.
Is there any additional setup I need to make to allow the output redirection?
I've tried running simple commands such as cmd.exe dir and I always get the same error when trying output redirection.

Wrong exe path, insufficient permissions or perhaps firewall. My bet is #2.

I don't think it is a path or permissions issue. As I mentioned, I see this error even if I just try to execute "cmd.exe dir" instead of running my ps1 file.

The problem turned out to be unrelated with C# or .Net. It was the test framework that is running my code the one with permission issues.
